# PowerShell script file modify time>10h and return a value if nothing is found

Tags: powershell, zabbix

I am trying to compose a script/one liner, which will find files which have been modified over 10 hours ago in a specific folder and if there are no files I need it to print some value or string.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\blaa\*.* | where {$_.Lastwritetime -lt (date).addhours(-10)}) | Format-table Name,LastWriteTime -HideTableHeaders"
```

With that one liner I am getting the wanted result when there are files with 
modify time over 10 hours, but I also need it to print value/string if there are 
no results, so that I can monitor it properly.
The reason for this is to utilize the script/one liner for monitoring purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Those cmdlet `Get-ChildItem` and where clause you have a would return null if nothing was found. You would have to account for that separately. [I would also caution the use of `Format-Table` for output unless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36358047/how-can-i-store-output-from-format-table-for-later-use/36358921#36358921) you are just using it for screen reading. If you wanted a "one-liner" you would could this. All PowerShell code can be a one liner if you want it to be.

```
$results = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\blaa\*.* | where {$_.Lastwritetime -lt (date).addhours(-10)} | Select Name,LastWriteTime; if($results){$results}else{"No files found matching criteria"}
```

You have an added bracket in your code, that might be a copy artifact, I had to remove. Coded properly would look like this

```
$results = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\blaa\*.*" | 
    Where-Object {$_.Lastwritetime -lt (date).addhours(-10)} | 
    Select Name,LastWriteTime

if($results){
    $results
}else{
    "No files found matching criteria"
}
```

Comment: Thank you bro! This seemed to do the trick, and yea I am only interested in screen reading since the monitoring platform seeks if a certain string in there or not.