# Select-Object & empty variable

Tags: powershell, report, psobject, get-wmiobject, select-object

I'm trying to build an boot report for my domain computers and send it automatically by mail.

though, I'm having trouble to put it into a variable to send using `Send-MailMessage` function.

Here's the piece of code:

```
foreach ($computer in $ComputerList){
     If (Test-Connection -ComputerName $Computer -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Quiet -Count 2  )
        {
        $ComInfo = (Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $Computer -Credential $Cred).LastBootUpTime
        #Convert the last boot time to a reader freindly date time format
        $BootTime = [System.Management.ManagementDateTimeConverter]::ToDateTime($ComInfo)
        $Canonical = (Get-ADComputer $Computer -Properties CanonicalName).CanonicalName
        New-Object PSObject -Property @{            
         'Computer Name'    = $Computer                  
         'Boot Time'    =  $BootTime
         'OU'        =  $Canonical
            }
        } #end-if test
     Else
     {
        $offlines = "$Computer desligado" 
     }
 }

$FinalReport | Select-Object 'Computer Name','Boot Time','OU' |
Sort-Object 'Boot Time' | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

But I'm getting it through powershell Interactive Window:

```
ComputerName     OU         Boot Time          
-------------    --         ---------          
PC60423          TI/PC60423 08/11/2017 11:31:38
PC60432          TI/PC60432 08/11/2017 09:26:52
PC60431          TI/PC60431 08/11/2017 08:56:53
PC60439          TI/PC60439 08/11/2017 08:42:31
PC60425          TI/PC60425 08/11/2017 10:11:43
PC60427          TI/PC60427 07/11/2017 17:07:26
PC34844          TI/PC34844 06/11/2017 15:21:06
PC42331          TI/PC42331 08/11/2017 08:10:52
PC47521          TI/PC47521 08/11/2017 07:09:01
PC36737          TI/PC36737 08/11/2017 07:47:11
PC47524          TI/PC47524 08/11/2017 08:22:24
PC30473          TI/PC30473 08/11/2017 10:06:33
PC29658          TI/PC29658 23/10/2017 10:27:06
```

Any ideas why is it happening?

EDIT:

solution was what these guys offered:

```
    $finalreport = foreach ($computer in $ComputerList)
{
     If (Test-Connection -ComputerName $Computer -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Quiet -Count 2  )
        {
        $ComInfo = (Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $Computer -Credential $Cred).LastBootUpTime
        $BootTime = [System.Management.ManagementDateTimeConverter]::ToDateTime($ComInfo)
        $Canonical = (Get-ADComputer $Computer -Properties CanonicalName).CanonicalName
        New-Object PSObject -Property @{            
         'Computer Name'    = $Computer 
         'OU'        =  $Canonical                 
         'Boot Time'    =  $BootTime

            }
        } #end-if test
     Else
     {
         $offlines = @($offlines + $computer )
     }
 }
```

Comment: In your code, $FinalReport isn't set to anything, but if you're wanting filtered output $FinalReport must be storing something.  You could start by putting `$Finalreport = ` before your ForEach loop.  Personally I'd set `$body = $FinalReport | Select-Object 'Computer Name','Boot Time','OU' |
Sort-Object 'Boot Time' | Format-Table -AutoSize ` then use that as the `-body` parameter of the Send-MailMessage cmdlet.

Comment: Oh, now this is getting even weirder, getting this as return:
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatStartData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData

Comment: @BryceMcDonald and OP: [Don't save results of `Format-Table`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36358921/3829407)

Comment: @Matt it really worked. perfectly reported now.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do `$FinalReport = foreach ($computer in $ComputerList){...`

Comment: it got me this as return: @{Computer Name=pc29658; OU=TI/pc29658; Boot Time=10/23/2017 10:27:06}

Comment: Sorry, I was mistaken. You will need to put the `$FinalReport =` in front of the `foreach` loop: `$FinalReport = foreach ($computer in $ComputerList){...`, I have changed this n my answer.