# Delete the ":" character from results

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to list only unique HomeDrive for all users in a Universal Security group and remove nested groups errors.
Thanks for your help.
Denis

I've tried `.TrimEnd(':')`, can't seem to figure out where to put it

```
$Group = "Universal Security group"
$HomeDrive = Get-ADGroupMember $Group | `
    ForEach-Object { 
        $UserName = $_.Name
        Try {
            #$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
            Get-ADUser $UserName -Properties HomeDrive | Select HomeDrive
            }
        Catch {
            Write-Host "Found a nested Group."
            }
        } | Sort-Object -Property 'HomeDrive' -Unique | Format-Table -HideTableHeaders | Out-String
Write-Host "$HomeDrive" -BackgroundColor DarkRed
```

The script does work but some users have their homedrives listed as only F while most are listed as F:. Basically making a lot of double entries and I do want the output to be only F. Also it generates 7 spaces after the `:`, That's why I have the background color.

Comment: What is `$HomeDrive = $HomeDrive.Split()` supposed to do? Is `$HomeDrive` defined earlier in your script?

Comment: Oh ... Please dont use Format-Table in the pipeline like that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36358047/how-can-i-store-output-from-format-table-for-later-use/36358921#36358921 that is _part_ of your issue.

Comment: @kuzimoto - sorry was not supposed to be included in my post. I have removed it.

Comment: No problem! But looks like mhu has it already figured out.

Comment: I forgot to add that I would also like to know how many times that drive letter was used. Denis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$group = "Universal Security group"
$homeDrives = Get-ADGroupMember $Group |
    ForEach-Object {
        if ($_.ObjectClass -eq "User")
        {    
            $user = Get-ADUser $_.Name -Properties "HomeDrive"
            $homeDrive = $user.HomeDrive.Trim().TrimEnd(":")
            return $homeDrive
        }
    } | Sort-Object -Unique

foreach ($homeDrive in $homeDrives)       
{
    Write-Host "Found home drive: $homeDrive" -BackgroundColor DarkRed
}
```

Comment: Thank you mhu this works perfectly. I knew I was close. Denis