# Passing date time as variable instead of where-object filter

Tags: powershell, datetime, variables

I am trying to use below code with date range as Where-Object filter but that is slowing down my output speed as well as unable to export to csv.

```
$Prids = get-content -Path C:\Temp\sqltest.txt
foreach ($prid in $prids){
$filterDate = [datetime]::Today.AddDays(-22)
Get-CdPac2000Problems  -PId $Prid  | Where-Object {$_.ClosedDate.Date -ge $filterDate} |ft PID,ClosedDate,ClosedByELID,ResponsibleGroup,ReferredDate -autosize
}
```

How can I change Where-Object to parameter that looks something like -closedate $variable like I did with -PID? The biggest struggle for me is to creating a datetime variable.

Comment: Depending on what you mean by `slowing down my output speed` that problem is you are using `Format-Table` which has to wait for all objects before they get displayed. That also breaks the objects and prevents `Export-CSV` from working.

Comment: About `Format-table`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36358047/how-can-i-store-output-from-format-table-for-later-use/36358921#36358921

Comment: To achieve exactly what you want, you would need to add that parameter (`-closedate`) to the `Get-CdPac2000Problems` function definition.

Answer (score -1):

First of, you should move the `$filterDate`out of the loop, second you should NEVER use Format-Table, and ABSOLUTELY NEVER in a loop.

Try this:

```
$filterDate = [datetime]::Today.AddDays(-22)
$Prids = get-content -Path C:\Temp\sqltest.txt
$Result = foreach ($prid in $prids){
    Get-CdPac2000Problems  -PId $Prid  | Where-Object {(Get-Date $_.ClosedDate.Date) -ge $filterDate}
}
$Result | Format-Table PID,ClosedDate,ClosedByELID,ResponsibleGroup,ReferredDate -autosize
```

One of the most beautyfull things in PowerShell is, that you can interfere directly with all objects. All methods and properties are preserved, when passing the objects to a variable or to the next command in a pipe. Format-Table converts objects to a table - something human readable and something stripped from methods and life.

Comment: If you caution its use you need to at least explain why

Comment: Done :-) BTW HDYK?

Comment: I am going mad why it doesnt show any error or output.

Comment: How do I know what?

Comment: starting to think there is some problem with connection. will try asap it is up and let you know :)

Comment: It all depends on, what is in your ClosedDate.Date parameter. If it is a string, the current answer is good, if it's a datetime objece, you need to ditch ```(getdate``` and ```)```

Comment: I think it is a datetime object. [DateTime]::Today.AddDays(-1) works fine for me except I believe it kind of slows down my output time. The DB has the date column format as "DD-MM-YYYY 00:00:00.000" (thats the format that worked for me when running db query from SQL Server Management STudio)

Comment: How many prids do you have, and what does the ```Get-CdPac2000Problems``` command do? Maybe you need to look for your time consuming task in the ```Get-CdPac2000Problems``` command.