# How to get this PowerShell output as a Table view?

Tags: powershell, directory, subdirectory

I need to get this PowerShell output in a Table view.Also, need to within quotation marks.

Current Output format:

```
Testing\Dump\DumpText-1.txt      Dump\DumpText-1.txt
Testing\Dump\DumpText-2.txt      Dump\DumpText-2.txt
Testing\Dump\SubDump1\DumpText-1.txt     SubDump1\DumpText-1.txt
Testing\Dump\SubDump1\DumpText-2.txt     SubDump1\DumpText-2.txt
Testing\Dump\SubDump2\Screenshot.png     SubDump2\Screenshot.png
```

Required Output Format:

```
"Testing\Dump\DumpText-1.txt"            "Dump\DumpText-1.txt"
"Testing\Dump\DumpText-2.txt"            "Dump\DumpText-2.txt"
"Testing\Dump\SubDump1\DumpText-1.txt"   "SubDump1\DumpText-1.txt"
"Testing\Dump\SubDump1\DumpText-2.txt"   "SubDump1\DumpText-2.txt"
"Testing\Dump\SubDump2\Screenshot.png"   "SubDump2\Screenshot.png"
```

My Script is:

```html
$directoryPath=$args[0]

Get-ChildItem $directoryPath -Recurse -Force | ForEach-Object -Process  { 
        
        if (!$_.PSIsContainer) {"$($_.FullName -creplace '^[^\\]*\\', '') `t` $($_.Directory.Name)\$($_.Name)"}
    
    }
```

Comment: Have a look at [Format-Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-table?view=powershell-5.1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [`PSCustomObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-pscustomobject) (and follow [Quoting Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules)):

```
Get-ChildItem $directoryPath -Recurse -Force -File |
    ForEach-Object -Process  { 
        [PSCustomObject]@{    
            fulln = """$($_.FullName -creplace '^[^\\]*\\', '')"""
            shrtn = """$(Join-Path -Path $_.Directory.Name -ChildPath $_.Name)"""
        }
    }
```

**Edit**

To hide the column headings from the table, apply [`Format-Table` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-table) as follows (read more at [Controlling column widths with Format-Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38554966/)):

```
Get-ChildItem $directoryPath -Recurse -Force -File |
    ForEach-Object -Process  { 
        [PSCustomObject]@{    
            fulln = """$($_.FullName -creplace '^[^\\]*\\', '')"""
            shrtn = """$(Join-Path -Path $_.Directory.Name -ChildPath $_.Name)"""
        }
    } | Format-Table -HideTableHeaders -AutoSize
```

However, `Format-` cmdlets are designed *for console/screen output only*. Read more in [Problem with Format- cmdlets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36358921/3439404)

Advanced script:

```
Param(
    [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$false, ValueFromPipeline)]
    [string]$directoryPath='\bat\filez',
    [Parameter()]
    [switch]$AsObject
)

$outObj = Get-ChildItem $directoryPath -Recurse -Force -File |
    ForEach-Object -Process  { 
        [PSCustomObject]@{    
            fulln = """$($_.FullName -creplace '^[^\\]*\\', '')"""
            shrtn = """$(Join-Path -Path $_.Directory.Name -ChildPath $_.Name)"""
        }
    }

if ( $AsObject.IsPresent ) {
    $outObj | Out-Default
} else {
    $outObj | Format-Table -HideTableHeaders -AutoSize
}
```

**Example 1**: `.\SO\67514630.ps1`

```
"bat\filez\more_real.eml"      "filez\more_real.eml"
"bat\filez\PS_preferences.bat" "filez\PS_preferences.bat"
"bat\filez\Sample Input.eml"   "filez\Sample Input.eml"
"bat\filez\SampleInput.eml"    "filez\SampleInput.eml"
"bat\filez\folder\xxx.csv"     "folder\xxx.csv"
```

**Example 2**: `.\SO\67514630.ps1 \bat\foo.txt -AsObject`

```
fulln                       shrtn
-----                       -----
"bat\files\676711\foo.txt"  "676711\foo.txt"
"bat\files\bubu\foo.txt"    "bubu\foo.txt"
"bat\Unusual Names\foo.txt" "Unusual Names\foo.txt"
"bat\foo.txt"               "bat\foo.txt"
```

Comment: How to change this script to not print the object names (fulln and shrtn) ?

Comment: @DhanushkaEkanayake Simply type names you do want there..

Comment: @DhanushkaEkanayake Use the following: `| Format-Table -HideTableHeaders` at the very end of the pipeline - or  use  `PathToYourScript.ps1 | Format-Table -HideTableHeaders` with the script unchanged.

Comment: Can you please tell me where do I should add the "| Format-Table -HideTableHeaders" in the script? (I add it in the very end, But it does not work)