# Poweshell alias for startTIME of Process

Tags: windows, powershell, variables, scripting, alias

I am trying to create a simple powershell script which will allow it to display the PID and the starttime of a process.

For the moment this is my code -->

```
$proc=$args[0]
    if (get-process -name $proc -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) { 
    $time= get-process $proc | Select-Object starttime |format-table -HideTableHeaders starttime 
    write-host  $proc $time} 
    else {write-host "non existant"}
```

When i look at the content of the variable $time , this is what is stored

```
> Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatStartData
> Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.GroupStartData Micr
> osoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData
> Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData
> Microsoft.Powe rShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData
> Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData
> Microsoft.PowerShell.Com mands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData
> Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData
> Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Inte rnal.Format.FormatEntryData
> Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData
> Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Forma t.FormatEntryData
> Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData
> Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEn tryData
> Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData
> Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.GroupEndData Micro
> soft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEndData
```

Basicaly , what i would like to end with is a script that shows every PID and Startime for a particular application. The $time var would need to store the date "2022-08-18 1:08:39 PM"

I would also create another variable called $id which would store the PID of each process.

```
1408 notepad Started 2022-08-18 1:08:39 PM
```

Or for applications with multiple processes

```
1409 chrome Started 2022-08-18 1:08:39 PM
14264 chrome Started 2022-08-18 1:08:40 PM
4567 chrome Started 202...
```

For the ones that have multiple processes , I guess I would use an foreach statement and go through every PID available in the variable ? Still new at this so if you have any advice on how to go about it would be appreciated , but in regards to what I know , a foreach statement would help me with this.

Comment: Why not use: `Get-Process -Name $proc | Select-Object -Property 'Id','Name','StartTime'`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I store output from Format-Table for later use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36358047/how-can-i-store-output-from-format-table-for-later-use)

Comment: The reason is because I want only the variable to store the ID numbers and i dont want it to include the title headers . That why I want to use "Format-table" to format the output to what i want it to look like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two common problems with your code:

- `Format-*` cmdlets emit output objects whose sole purpose is to provide *formatting instructions* to PowerShell's for-display output-formatting system. In short: **only ever use `Format-*` cmdlets to format data *for display*, never for subsequent *programmatic processing*** - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55174715/45375) for more information.
- The reason you tried to use `Format-Table` to begin with was in order to get just the `.StartTime` property *value*. The proper way **to get [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) to output just a property *value*** is to use the **`-ExpandProperty`** parameter, i.e. 
  `-ExpandProperty starttime` instead of `[-Property] starrttime`.

  - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48807857/45375) for details and alternatives.

---

A PowerShell-idiomatic solution would look something like this:

```
$proc = $args[0]

# Process all matching processes, if any.
Get-Process $proc -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
  ForEach-Object {
    '{0} {1} Started {2}' -f $_.Id, $_.Name, $_.StartTime
  }

# $? contains $false if an error occurred in the previous statement.
if (-not $?) { Write-Warning "Non-existent: $proc" }
```

That is, matching processes are processed one by one using [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object), and in the [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (`{ ... }`) passed to it you can refer to the process-info object ([`System.Diagnostics.Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Diagnostics.Process)) at hand via the [automatic `$_` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#_) variable, allowing you to access the properties of interest directly on that object. The [`-f` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#format-operator--f) is used to synthesize the output strings in the desired format.

Sample output:

```
56204 bash Started 8/18/2022 2:15:25 PM
56245 bash Started 8/18/2022 2:15:28 PM
```

Comment: @FrancoReyes, title headers are purely a _display-formatting_ concept, which doesn't come into play here. The code in this answer deals with (data) _objects_ and their _properties_ - that's the beauty of PowerShell: you're dealing with objects (instances of .NET types)  whose properties and methods you can access / call using standard OOP techniques.

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer for my own question. If anyone else is wondering why this happens , it is all explained in this post.

[How can I store output from Format-Table for later use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36358047/how-can-i-store-output-from-format-table-for-later-use)