# Powershell is not export value to a csv file

Tags: powershell

I have below records in a file:

```
 id user        mart  desc                                                                                                
 -- ----        ----- --------                                                                                                
  1 test_1          3 test result 1...
  2 test_2          3 test result 2
```

and I want to write it to a .csv file in powershell with below command:

```
Get-Content .\test | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | Out-File txt.csv
```

I am expect a csv file with below value:

```
id,user,mart,desc
1,test_1,3,test result 1
2,test_2,3,test result 2
```

but somehow the output csv file is like below:

```
"PSPath","PSParentPath","PSChildName","PSDrive","PSProvider","ReadCount","Length"
"C:\test","C:\question","test","C","Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem","1","126"
"C:\test","C:\question","test","C","Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem","2","126"
"C:\test","C:\question","test","C","Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem","3","126"
"C:\test","C:\question","test","C","Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem","4","126"
```

Is there any idea why it didnt export the proper value to csv.

I am expect a csv file with below value:

```
id,user,mart,desc
1,test_1,3,test result 1
2,test_2,3,test result 2
```

Comment: Does this answer your question: [How can I store output from Format-Table for later use](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36358921/1701026)

Comment: Why don't you use Export-CSV ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### Background information:

- [`ConvertTo-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/ConvertTo-Csv) and [`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Export-Csv) operate on (complex) *objects* and *their properties*, not on the *strings* that [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Get-Content) returns from *plain-text* files.

  - `[string]` instances have just *one* property, `.Length`, and their *content* isn't a *property*, so converting strings to CSV is pointless, because you'll get a *single* output column named `Length` that simply contains the length (character count) of each input string; e.g.:

    ```bash
    'abc', 'de' | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
    ```

    - Output (the values of the only column are the lengths of the input strings):

      ```bash
      "Length"
      "3"
      "2"
      ```
  - The reason you have *additional* columns in your (useless) CSV output is that the strings returned by `Get-Content` are decorated with [ETS (Extended Type System)](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/6763) properties such as `.PSPath` containing metadata about the file that the lines were read from.

    - For the sake of completeness: You could bypass these additional properties by inserting a `ForEach-Object ToString` segment after your `Get-Content` call (but it still won't get you useful CSV output).
- Therefore, to provide meaningful input to `ConvertTo-Csv` / `Export-Csv` based on a *file*, that file's content must be parsed into *objects with properties*, which these cmdlets then convert to CSV data with columns named for the properties, and field values based on the properties's values.

  - Only text files using a *structured format* for *programmatic processing* allow such parsing to be performed robustly; examples of such formats are JSON, XML, and CSV itself.
  - By contrast, your text file uses a *for-display* format for the *human observer*, which is *not* suitable for robust programmatic processing; case in point: the `...` at the end of the first value in the `desc` column suggest that the column value was *truncated*.

---

##### Solution:

- In principle, **if you get to control how your input file is created, create it in a *structured* text format**, as noted.

  - Notably, do *not* use the *for-display* format that results from redirecting command output to a file with `>` or `Out-File`; neither should you use any of the `Format-*` cmdlets (which `>` and `Out-File` *implicitly* use).
  - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36358921/1701026)<sup>Thanks, [iRon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1701026/iron).</sup> and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55174715/45375) for more information.
  - Of course, if you're free to choose a structured format, you could just create your file in CSV format to begin with.
- **Otherwise you have to resort to - invariably brittle - *text parsing*. As noted, data may already have been lost in the for-display representation.**

The following **transforms your fixed-column-width input file into CSV**, based on the following **assumptions**:

- The start of a column *name* implies where all *values* in that column start as well.
- No column names contain *embedded spaces* or embedded `,`
- No column values are *multiline* values.

```bash
# Read the file into header line, separator line (to be ignored, and
# data lines, ignoring blank (empty or all-whitespace) lines.
$headerLine, $separatorLine, $dataLines = @(Get-Content .\test) -match '\S'

# Get the indices of the characters that end the columns.
# + -1 adds an extra array element that is a placeholder for the end of the line.
$colEndIndices = [regex]::Matches($headerLine, ' \S').Index + -1

# Transform the header line into a CSV header row.
$csvHeader = (-split $headerLine) -join ','

# Transform the data lines into in-memory CSV rows.
$csvData =
  $dataLines |
  ForEach-Object {
    # Split the line at hand into fields, trim each field and enclose it in "..."
    $pos = 0
    $fields = 
      foreach ($colEndIndex in $colEndIndices) {
        if ($colEndIndex -eq -1) { $colEndIndex = $_.Length - 1 } 
        '"' + $_.Substring($pos, $colEndIndex - $pos + 1).Replace('"', '""').Trim() + '"'
        $pos += $colEndIndex - $pos + 1
      }
    # Output the fields as a CSV line
    $fields -join ','
  }

# Save the in-memory CSV data to a file.
$csvHeader, $csvData | Set-Content txt.csv
```

Given your sample input file, the above saves the following content to `txt.csv`:

```bash
id,user,mart,desc
"1","test_1","3","test result 1..."
"2","test_2","3","test result 2"
```

The *unconditional* enclosure of the fields in `"..."` simplifies the code, but it wouldn't be hard to modify it to use double-quoting only when actually needed, namely for field values that contain `,` and newlines (n/a here).

To CSV parsers it shouldn't matter whether fields that contain neither are optionally enclosed in `"..."` or not.

Comment: In general, I agree 10000% on the for-display vs structured data discussion. In this particular case, though, it appears the data happens to also be a fixed-width format that _may_ be readable.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn, yes, fixed-width data _can_ be parseable, if it is unambiguous (and the solution in the answer does so), but note that the specific format of the sample data suggests that PowerShell's own `Format-Table` cmdlet was (possibly implicitly) used to create the file, and, if so, that the presence of `...` in a column indicates a _truncated_ value.